# Cборка андроид ММ 6.0.1

Tags: c++, c, фреймворк

Получаю ошибку, которая связана с фреймворками:

```
frameworks/av/services/audiopolicy/AudioPolicyInterfaceImplLegacy.cpp: In member function 'virtual audio_io_handle_t android::AudioPolicyService::getInput(audio_source_t, uint32_t, audio_format_t, audio_channel_mask_t, int)':
frameworks/av/services/audiopolicy/AudioPolicyInterfaceImplLegacy.cpp:233:91: error: no matching function for call to 'android::AudioEffect::AudioEffect(effect_uuid_t*, int, int, int, int&, audio_io_handle_t&)'
         sp<AudioEffect> fx = new AudioEffect(&effect->mUuid, -1, 0, 0, audioSession, input);
                                                                                           ^
frameworks/av/services/audiopolicy/AudioPolicyInterfaceImplLegacy.cpp:233:91: note: candidates are:
In file included from frameworks/av/services/audiopolicy/AudioPolicyService.h:32:0,
                 from frameworks/av/services/audiopolicy/AudioPolicyInterfaceImplLegacy.cpp:21:
frameworks/av/include/media/AudioEffect.h:247:5: note: android::AudioEffect::AudioEffect(const char*, const android::String16&, const char*, int32_t, android::AudioEffect::effect_callback_t, void*, int, audio_io_handle_t)
     AudioEffect(const char *typeStr,
     ^
frameworks/av/include/media/AudioEffect.h:247:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'effect_uuid_t* {aka effect_uuid_s*}' to 'const char*'
frameworks/av/include/media/AudioEffect.h:234:5: note: android::AudioEffect::AudioEffect(const effect_uuid_t*, const android::String16&, const effect_uuid_t*, int32_t, android::AudioEffect::effect_callback_t, void*, int, audio_io_handle_t)
     AudioEffect(const effect_uuid_t *type,
     ^
frameworks/av/include/media/AudioEffect.h:234:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'int' to 'const android::String16&'
frameworks/av/include/media/AudioEffect.h:209:5: note: android::AudioEffect::AudioEffect(const android::String16&)
     AudioEffect(const String16& opPackageName);
     ^
frameworks/av/include/media/AudioEffect.h:209:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 6 provided
In file included from frameworks/av/services/audioflinger/AudioFlinger.h:44:0,
                 from frameworks/av/media/mediaserver/main_mediaserver.cpp:32:
frameworks/native/include/binder/BinderService.h: In instantiation of 'static android::status_t android::BinderService<SERVICE>::publish(bool) [with SERVICE = android::AudioPolicyService; android::status_t = int]':
frameworks/native/include/binder/BinderService.h:49:41:   required from 'static void android::BinderService<SERVICE>::instantiate() [with SERVICE = android::AudioPolicyService]'
frameworks/av/media/mediaserver/main_mediaserver.cpp:136:29:   required from here
frameworks/native/include/binder/BinderService.h:41:45: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'android::AudioPolicyService'
                 new SERVICE(), allowIsolated);
                                             ^
In file included from frameworks/av/media/mediaserver/main_mediaserver.cpp:38:0:
frameworks/av/services/audiopolicy/AudioPolicyService.h:40:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'android::AudioPolicyService':
 class AudioPolicyService :
       ^
In file included from frameworks/av/services/audiopolicy/AudioPolicyService.h:30:0,
                 from frameworks/av/media/mediaserver/main_mediaserver.cpp:38:
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:45:22: note:  virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::setDeviceConnectionState(audio_devices_t, audio_policy_dev_state_t, const char*, const char*)
     virtual status_t setDeviceConnectionState(audio_devices_t device,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:61:22: note:  virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::getOutputForAttr(const audio_attributes_t*, audio_io_handle_t*, audio_session_t, audio_stream_type_t*, uid_t, uint32_t, audio_format_t, audio_channel_mask_t, audio_output_flags_t, audio_port_handle_t, const audio_offload_info_t*)
     virtual status_t getOutputForAttr(const audio_attributes_t *attr,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:72:22: note:  virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::startOutput(audio_io_handle_t, audio_stream_type_t, audio_session_t)
     virtual status_t startOutput(audio_io_handle_t output,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:75:22: note:  virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::stopOutput(audio_io_handle_t, audio_stream_type_t, audio_session_t)
     virtual status_t stopOutput(audio_io_handle_t output,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:78:18: note:  virtual void android::IAudioPolicyService::releaseOutput(audio_io_handle_t, audio_stream_type_t, audio_session_t)
     virtual void releaseOutput(audio_io_handle_t output,
                  ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:81:23: note:  virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::getInputForAttr(const audio_attributes_t*, audio_io_handle_t*, audio_session_t, uid_t, uint32_t, audio_format_t, audio_channel_mask_t, audio_input_flags_t, audio_port_handle_t)
     virtual status_t  getInputForAttr(const audio_attributes_t *attr,
                       ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:90:22: note:  virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::startInput(audio_io_handle_t, audio_session_t)
     virtual status_t startInput(audio_io_handle_t input,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:92:22: note:  virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::stopInput(audio_io_handle_t, audio_session_t)
     virtual status_t stopInput(audio_io_handle_t input,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:94:18: note:  virtual void android::IAudioPolicyService::releaseInput(audio_io_handle_t, audio_session_t)
     virtual void releaseInput(audio_io_handle_t input,
                  ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:127:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::listAudioPorts(audio_port_role_t, audio_port_type_t, unsigned int*, audio_port*, unsigned int*)
     virtual status_t listAudioPorts(audio_port_role_t role,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:134:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::getAudioPort(audio_port*)
     virtual status_t getAudioPort(struct audio_port *port) = 0;
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:137:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::createAudioPatch(const audio_patch*, audio_patch_handle_t*)
     virtual status_t createAudioPatch(const struct audio_patch *patch,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:141:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::releaseAudioPatch(audio_patch_handle_t)
     virtual status_t releaseAudioPatch(audio_patch_handle_t handle) = 0;
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:144:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::listAudioPatches(unsigned int*, audio_patch*, unsigned int*)
     virtual status_t listAudioPatches(unsigned int *num_patches,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:148:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::setAudioPortConfig(const audio_port_config*)
     virtual status_t setAudioPortConfig(const struct audio_port_config *config) = 0;
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:150:18: note:     virtual void android::IAudioPolicyService::registerClient(const android::sp<android::IAudioPolicyServiceClient>&)
     virtual void registerClient(const sp<IAudioPolicyServiceClient>& client) = 0;
                  ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:152:18: note:     virtual void android::IAudioPolicyService::setAudioPortCallbacksEnabled(bool)
     virtual void setAudioPortCallbacksEnabled(bool enabled) = 0;
                  ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:154:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::acquireSoundTriggerSession(audio_session_t*, audio_io_handle_t*, audio_devices_t*)
     virtual status_t acquireSoundTriggerSession(audio_session_t *session,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:158:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::releaseSoundTriggerSession(audio_session_t)
     virtual status_t releaseSoundTriggerSession(audio_session_t session) = 0;
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:160:26: note:     virtual audio_mode_t android::IAudioPolicyService::getPhoneState()
     virtual audio_mode_t getPhoneState() = 0;
                          ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:162:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::registerPolicyMixes(android::Vector<android::AudioMix>, bool)
     virtual status_t registerPolicyMixes(Vector<AudioMix> mixes, bool registration) = 0;
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:164:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::startAudioSource(const audio_port_config*, const audio_attributes_t*, audio_io_handle_t*)
     virtual status_t startAudioSource(const struct audio_port_config *source,
                      ^
frameworks/av/include/media/IAudioPolicyService.h:167:22: note:     virtual android::status_t android::IAudioPolicyService::stopAudioSource(audio_io_handle_t)
     virtual status_t stopAudioSource(audio_io_handle_t handle) = 0;
                      ^
make: *** [/home/mirsaid02/CM13.0/out/target/product/glacier/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libaudiopolicyservice_intermediates/AudioPolicyInterfaceImplLegacy.o] Ошибка 1
make: *** Ожидание завершения заданий...
make: *** [/home/mirsaid02/CM13.0/out/target/product/glacier/obj/EXECUTABLES/mediaserver_intermediates/main_mediaserver.o] Ошибка 1
```

Comment: Всё же написано в ошибках. Или Вам перевод с английского не сделать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.